# Triggering build of another project in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I just starting using maven in my new project.
I am trying to create artifacts(java files) of a project A into another project B in order to resolve their cyclic dependency.
If I run the whole build for the first time,its working fine. The jar of B contains classes of both project A and B.
However, if I make changes to only project B , and run the build, only project B is running and build is failing . Thats because sine no changes are done to project A, maven is not running it and the artifacts are also not getting generated.
Can anyone advise how can I trigger the build of a project even though no changes are done to it.

Answer (score 0):

exec mvn with clean phase! i.e.

```
mvn clean package
```

Comment: The build is running in jenkins so how do I do it using pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Phases are actually mapped to underlying goals. The specific goals executed per phase is dependant upon the packaging type of the project. For example, package executes jar:jar if the project type is a JAR, and war:war if the project type is - you guessed it - a WAR.

An interesting thing to note is that phases and goals may be executed in sequence.

```
mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies package
```

This command will clean the project, copy dependencies, and package the project

```
mvn site
```

This phase generates a site based upon information on the project's pom. You can look at the documentation generated under target/site.